# Setting user name and password to browser from the Batch file

Tags: batch-file, browser

I have created a batch file to open a browser. But I need to know how to interpret the user name and password from the batch file.

Below is my batch file. Can anyone please help?

FYI, I'm just using the normal .bat file (from notepad).

```
@ECHO ON 
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE https://www.myhcl.com/Login/home.aspx
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in batch

Comment: Internet explorer can be managed comparatively easy through its activex controls -  e.g. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_internet_whois.php#InternetExplorer

Answer (score 0):

There is no "native" way for a bat file to interact with a window. I would use powershell or VB script for this task but it will be quite a mess.

An easy way is to use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). It's realy simple and allows you to fully interact with a browser. You could ither use the AutoIt interpreter from within your bat file to manipulate the browser window or just create an au3 or even an exe file that starts the browser and enters the login data.

If you decide to use AutoIt and need help with the script just ask me.